# Word 2016 equation font keeps auto-resetting to Hindi fonts

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, fonts, microsoft-word-2016, equation-editor

In Word 2016, when I insert an equation, it shows it to me correctly.

However, when I save the document and re-open it, the font gets automatically changed to Hindi fonts. Each time I change the font and save the document and then re-open it, it keeps going back to Hindi.

My default office language is set to English.

I have tried uninstalling the Hindi fonts but to no avail. When I uninstall one font, it just picks up another Hindi font.

I have also tried reinstalling Word itself, but that too didn't help.

Please guide what should I do to change the default equation language. I have become somewhat frustrated with this problem since the last many months.

Comment: Create a blank document and insert an equation. Will the issue still occur? Generally, there is only one font supported in equations so far: Cambria Math. You can right-click an equation and select Font to have a check. Do you mean that your Asian Text Font is a kind of Hindi fonts? What's your editing language in Word? You can click File > Options > Language to have a check. In addition, you can also try to [reset user options and registry settings in Word](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/word/reset-options-and-settings-in-word)

Comment: @HerbGu Thank you! That worked :)

Could you please add your suggestion as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: OK. I'm glad to hear you have resolved the issue and my suggestion helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, there is only one font supported in equations so far: Cambria Math. You can right-click an equation and select Font to have a check.

It's recommended that you try to [reset user options and registry settings in Word](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/word/reset-options-and-settings-in-word).

Please note: This article contains information about how to modify the registry. Make sure to back up the registry before you modify it. Make sure that you know how to restore the registry if a problem occurs. For more information about how to back up, restore, and modify the registry, see [How to back up and restore the registry in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/322756/how-to-back-up-and-restore-the-registry-in-windows).